# Checks if Blob exists in Azure Storage in Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-lake

I am using this action "Checks if Blob exists in Azure Storage" to check if a blob object (file) exists in the storage account or not. It is Data Lake Blob. It is able to give me proper true or false when I use it one storage but just gives an "Internal server' error with another storage account.
Both storages are identical in terms of settings. I just cannot trace why it does not work with one storage account and works perfectly fine with the other
Has anyone faced a similar issue?

To replicate -

1. Create a new workflow in a logic app std.
2. Add recurrence as the trigger
3. Add action - Checks if Blob exists in Azure Storage - connect it to the storage account, give container name, give blob name.

Both the storages belong to the same resource group.

Screenshots below:
[image: Network Settings]

[image: Other Setttings]

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could make this work ideally. Make sure you are changing the connection using Change connection and having the connection name the same as the previous storage account connection.

[image]

In my case, the code view of the first connection

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Checks_if_Blob_exists_in_Azure_Storage": {
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "blobName": "<BLOB_NAME>",
                        "containerName": "containerblob"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "AzureBlob",
                        "operationId": "blobExists",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

Code view of the second connection

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Checks_if_Blob_exists_in_Azure_Storage": {
                "inputs": {
                    "parameters": {
                        "blobName": "<BLOB_NAME>",
                        "containerName": "containerblob"
                    },
                    "serviceProviderConfiguration": {
                        "connectionName": "AzureBlob-2",
                        "operationId": "blobExists",
                        "serviceProviderId": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ServiceProvider"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "kind": "Stateful"
}
```

After changing connectionName of the second storage account i.e., AzureBlob-2 to AzureBlob this was working fine.

Alternatively, Remove the previous connection to Azure storage, save the workflow and then add the `Checks if Blob exists in Azure Storage` action with the new storage account.

Comment: Hi Swetha, Thank you for your response. I am sure the problem is not with the connection. As a matter of fact, I am using the change connection button to switch by storages. As I mentioned in my initial post. I am able to check for the existence of a blob, read and write in storage 1. However, cannot do any of these with storage 2. I tried creating a consumption logic app, can can connect - check, read, create blobs in storage 2. however, iit does not work with the STD logic app workflows

Comment: @MK-ML, Have you tried removing the api connection and add the storage-2 connection string because I could able to reproduce from my side and see everything was working fine and yes I did it with the Consumption plan and Standard plan both works fine.

Comment: I tried in a completely separate azure account. Created a storage account (with FTP ON) and then created a workflow. Tried using the If blob exists action and even in this different account - it still gives me the same error. The point I am trying to convey here is that here in this different azure account, there arent any existing connections. Just one simple connection to the storage and a single workflow in a new std logic app and yet the same error.

Comment: Also with regards to your suggestion - "Have you tried removing the api connection and add the storage-2 connection string" - In this new account, i tried it first as I have written above then removed the api connection and then went back to the design view of the workflow. The Add new button does not work and does not show anything in that list.

Comment: So I have deleted the action - Check Blob If exists and re-added and setup a new connection. When I run it, it still fails with the same - Internal server error as in the attached screenshot.

Comment: One more thing - With a consumption based Logic app - it works!